# Do the Zoombini's names mean anything?

Tags: zoombinis

In Zoombinis, Zoombinis are each assigned a name. These names don't help solve puzzles, so what are they for, if anything? Is it so you don't confuse, for example, Cuaqu with Oplie (Actual Zoombini names)? How are they decided?

Is there any significance for Zoombini names?

Comment: I thought so. However, I'm not sure why they were implemented if that's the case. The only thing I can think of is to distinguish between Zoombinis. But is that really important?

Comment: Eh, might as well make an answer out of that, there's probably not any actual proof to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Zoombini names have no particular significance.**

While I don't have any particular proof, I doubt there's any to be had in this case. The names are just randomly generated, probably from one or more lists, and likely you can get multiple different names for the same combination of parts, so they're not even bound to "particular" Zoombinis. It's an educational kids game, after all, in all likelihood it's simply there to add a cute touch for children playing the game.

Comment: I didn't think about that last point (it being an educational children's game) at all. I guess that makes perfect sense. Now, off to play more Zoombinis! :D